# How to subscribe Kafka dynamic topic using Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus, reactive-kafka

I have a use case is that - there is a system that will generate different kafka topics in runtime, meanwhile, I have a component that needs to subscribe a specific topic on demand.

I gone through the related Quarkus document, but still didn't figure out a way of doing that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69062279/175554 may help

Comment: You can use Camel Kafka Quarkus extensions, which can be configured also dynamically at runtime. Another option would be to use Custom ConfigSource and dynamically change the configuration in memory.

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/3.5.x/reference/extensions/kafka.html

Comment: @ozkanpakdil am afrid this is not help, as I dont know which topic needs to be subscribe at start up.

Comment: @BorislavGizdov this is an idea! but to be honest, i don't want to introduce camel as a dependency, since for my case, I just need to subscribe data from Kafka, not necessary need other fancy features from camel.

Comment: Then you can try this 
https://quarkus.io/guides/config-extending-support and configure Kafka runtime.

Comment: I could not find a way quarkus API to change on the runtime, [this](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/blob/master/kafka-dynamic-topic/src/main/java/com/mascix/DynamicKafkaConsumer.java) is the closest I can get which is directly using kafka consumer.